# Chinese URL windows and IOS encode different

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I'm from server get some data, parameters, the parameters of which are submitted to Chinese need code, I tested the windows on XE4 is normal, to IOS on error.
`HttpEncode (UTF8Encode ('some Chinese'))` the coding result is not the same in windows and IOS. I won't get the same results, and then submitted to the server received is garbled, everybody can help me to have a look?

Comment: Have a look at *what*?

Comment: Please show us: a) where the string came from, b) how you 're sending it to the server, c) what the server receives. Also, not `'some chinese'`, but the actual string of Chinese characters.

Comment: Can you get some help with writing the question. I can see that english is not your native language, this is making the question hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what the problem is, but it seems you are having a text encoding-decoding mismatch. I understand you are encoding the text yourself, but the two destinations (windows and ios) are decoding it differently. I had this problem with Arabic and didn't understand what was happening until I read this:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Then life was good again. I hope this helps :)